# Try to select null as columnName with table alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue where I am working on table aliases and ran into a weird issue. I am able to use null as column name when I am not using table alias, but if I use a table alias I run into issues.

```
works!

select top 10 eid, null as emp_no from employee 

does not work!!

select top 10 e.eid, null as e.emp_no from employee e
```

Is there a way out? I am running into an issue when I join with another table.

```
Trying to make it work !

select top 10 e.eid, null as e.emp_no, ed.desgination from employee e 
inner join employee_designations ed on e.eid=ed.eid


Error 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

Comment: Sorry I miss read your question. Its because null is not part of any table. In e.emp_no e signifies a table a null does not belong to a table its a keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
select top 10 e.eid, null as emp_no from employee e
```

You can alias `NULL`, but SQL will throw a hissy-fit if you claim that it's from table alias `e`.

**UPDATE**:

To use the `NULL` in a join, turn it into a subquery:

```
SELECT  e.eid
        , e.emp_no
FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 10 eid
                    , NULL AS emp_no
            FROM    employee
        ) AS e
```

Alias your subquery as `e` and now SQL will happily accept `NULL` as `e.emp_no`.

Comment: this would be an issue when I join

Comment: @macha: Updated answer for join.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but this error is throwed because when you assign a value to a column, this is not your table column anymore, is just a 'virtual' column, so that's why you can't give the table alias to this column, simply because this is not a column table

why? It would throw back `Ambiguous column name` if tables had the same column names, but you are assigning a value, so you aren't getting this column names, you could simple do `null as emp_no` in your query synthax, because this emp_no isn't any column from inner join synthax, try just calling:

```
select top 10 e.eid, null as emp_no, ed.desgination from employee e 
inner join employee_designations ed on e.eid=ed.eid
```